# Walking through a relatively basic C++ Template

Tags: c++, templates, set, constants, walkthrough

Our instructor has asked us to walk through a Template and explain what the various pieces of it are doing:

```
Template<class T> set<T> set<T>:: setDifference(const Set<T> &that) const
```

Here is what I've got so far:

```
Template<class T>: declares the new template

set<T>: states the return type of our template

set<T>: pretty confused about the second set, possibly the class name?

setDifference: Calls on our setDifference function

const Set<T> &that: 
Parameters of setDifference, states set<T> cannot be modified within                          
setDifference or put on the left hand side of the equation. "&that" references "that"     
memory location to use/call

const (at the end): 
Our function can only be called by a const object of the class
nor can it call any non-const member functions or change member variables.
```

If anyone could please correct/add to what I already have I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What you have pasted looks like an incorrect version of the definition of a templated class's member function. Please correct your code first.

Comment: If you make a chat room, I'll quite happily walk you through this. However such questions aren't really suitable for SO as it's quite broad and may be decided that it lacks basic understanding.

Comment: `template<class T> set<T> set<T>::setDifference(const set<T> &that) const;` - pretty sure that is what this was *supposed* to look like.

Comment: @Pradhan it is almost correct except `:` should be `::` (and of course no capitalization), isn't it?

Comment: @OMGtechy Unfortunately I don't have over 20 reputation yet, so I am unable to create a chat room. Is there any other method of communication we could use?

Comment: @vsoftco You are right. And it doesn't look like it was edited after my post. For some reason, I thought the OP was asking about declaring a template class and wanted a clarification.

Comment: @BenThomas (comment deleted - skyping OP)

Comment: Your code is wrong: `template` is correct, not `Template`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the beginning of the definition of the member function setDifference outside of its class body

```
template <class T>
struct set{
//...
    set setDifference( const set& that) const;
};
template<class T>
set<T> set<T>::setDifference( const set<T>& that) const
{
    set<T> newInstance (...);
    //implementation of setDifference: newInstance = this - that
    return newInstance;
}
```

- The return type is a newly created instance of the set class
- The second set is indeed the class name; needed because setDifference lives in the namespace `set<T>`
- you're right about the rest